# Валидация модели в Django. В чем моя ошибка?

Tags: python, django

Задача:
(POST) /api/v1/goods/ - создать товар в магазине.
Формат запроса: application/json.
Пример запроса: 
{
  "title": "Сыр \"Российский\"",
  "description": "Очень вкусный сыр, да еще и российский.",
  "price": 100
}.
Ограничения:
- Все поля обязательные 
- title - не пустая строка, не длиннее 64 символов.
- description - не пустая строка, не длиннее 1024 символов.
- price - не пустая строка (которую можно перевести в целое число) или целое число, значения от 1 до 1000000.
Возможные ответы:
- 201 - товар успешно сохранен.
  Пример ответа:
    {"id": 112}.
- 400 - запрос не прошел валидацию.

models.py.

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    """Модель товара."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

views.py

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views import View
from .models import Item, Review

class AddItemView(View):
    """View для создания товара."""

    def post(self, request):
        item = Item(request.POST)

        if item.full_clean():
            data = Item(title = item.title, description = item.description, price = item.price)
            data.save()
            #data = {'id': data.id}

            return JsonResponse(data, status=201)
        else:
            return JsonResponse(data, status=400)
```

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что здесь есть ошибка?

Comment: @andreymal запускаю тесты, получаю ошибку. _TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'_

Comment: Потому что код `Item(request.POST)` не является корректным. Почитайте в документации, как работать с моделями и как создавать объекты. А лучше сразу возьмите ModelForm, потому что у форм намного более богатые возможности по валидации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что этот кусочек из [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django)

```
item = Item(request.POST)
```

А этот из Models

```
data = Item(title = item.title, description = item.description, price = item.price)
```

Вам нужно [создать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) форму из своей модели в файле forms.py, подключить ее, а потом уже передавать ей request.POST